# No me actualiza los usuarios

Tags: php, mysql, php7

Estoy intentando actualizar un usuario, pero **no me lo esta haciendo**, por otro lado no me muesta ningun `error`.

Este es mi fichero `metodosCrud.php`, la cual contiene una unica clase diferentes funciones tales como `mostrarDatos()` , `insertarDatos()`,`actualizar()` . Esta ultima (`actualizar()`) es la unica que **no funciona**.

```
<?php 

    class metodos{

        public function mostrarDatos($sql){
            $c = new conexion();
            $conexion = $c->conectar();

            $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

            //MYSQLI_ASSOC => devuelve en forma de array asociativo ($array['nombre'])
            return mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        }


        public function insertarDatos($datos){
            $c = new conexion();
            $conexion = $c->conectar();

            $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre,apellidos,usuario,email,password)      
             VALUES ('$datos[0]','$datos[1]','$datos[2]','$datos[3]','$datos[4]')";

            return $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
        }


        public function actualizar($datos){
            $c = new conexion();
            $conexion = $c->conectar();

            $sql = "
            UPDATE usuarios 
            SET 
            nombre = '$datos[1]', 
            apellidos = '$datos[2]', 
            usuario = '$datos[3]', 
            email = '$datos[4]' 
            password = '$datos[5]' 

            WHERE id = '$datos[0]'";

            return $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
        }
    }

 ?>
```

Reitero que la **unica** que **no funciona** es la funcion de **actualizar**.

Este fichero **metodosCrud.php** es llamada en el siguiente fichero:

**actualizar.php**

```
    require_once "../conexion.php";
    require_once "../metodosCrud.php";


    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];



    $datos = array(
        $id,
        $nombre,
        $apellidos,
        $usuario,
        $email,
        $password
    );


    $obj = new metodos();

    if ($obj->actualizar($datos) == 1) {
            header("location:../index.php");
    }
    else{ 
        echo "Fallo al actualizar usuario";
    var_dump($datos);
    }


 ?>
```

Y a su vez, esta fichero (**actualizar.php**) es llamado la **vista** :

**editar.php**

```
<?php 
require_once "conexion.php";

$obj = new conexion();
$conexion = $obj->conectar();
$id  = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "SELECT nombre,apellidos,usuario,email,password FROM usuarios WHERE id = '$id'";


$result = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

$ver = mysqli_fetch_row($result);





 ?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Actualizar Form</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="procesos/actualizar.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" hidden=""  name="id" value="<?php echo $id ?>">
        <label>Nombre:</label>
        <p></p>
        <input type="text" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $ver[0] ?>">
        <p></p>
        <label>Apellidos:</label>
        <p></p>
        <input type="text" name="apellidos" value="<?php echo $ver[1] ?>">
        <p></p>
        <label>Usuario:</label>
        <p></p>
        <input type="text" name="usuario" value="<?php echo $ver[2] ?>">
        <p></p>
        <label>Email:</label>
        <p></p>
        <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $ver[3] ?>">
        <p></p>     
        <label>Password:</label>
        <p></p>
        <input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $ver[4] ?>">
        <p></p>
        <button type="submit">Editar</button>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Finalmente, para llegar a la **vista de edicion** se hace desde : 

 **index.php**

```
<?php 
    require_once "conexion.php";
    require_once "metodosCrud.php";
 ?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>



    <form action="procesos/insertar.php" method="POST">
        <label>Nombre:</label>
        <p></p>
        <input type="text" name="nombre">
        <p></p>
        <label>Apellidos:</label>
        <p></p>
        <input type="text" name="apellidos">
        <p></p>
        <label>Usuario:</label>
        <p></p>
        <input type="text" name="usuario">
        <p></p>
        <label>Email:</label>
        <p></p>
        <input type="email" name="email">
        <p></p>     
        <label>Password:</label>
        <p></p>
        <input type="password" name="password">
        <p></p>
        <button type="submit">Agregar</button>

    </form>


    <br>
    <br>

    <table style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Nombre</td>
            <td>Apellidos</td>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>Usuario</td>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td>ACTUALIZAR</td>
        </tr>
<?php 
    $obj = new metodos();
    $sql = "SELECT id,nombre,apellidos,usuario,email,password FROM usuarios";
    $datos = $obj->mostrarDatos($sql);

    foreach ($datos as $dato) {


 ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php  echo $dato['nombre']?></td>
            <td><?php  echo $dato['apellidos']?></td>
            <td><?php  echo $dato['email']?></td>
            <td><?php  echo $dato['usuario']?></td>
            <td><?php  echo $dato['password']?></td>
            <td>
                <a href="editar.php?id=<?php echo $dato['id'] ?>">Editar</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
<?php
    }
  ?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Expuesto todo lo que estoy haciendo digo que a la hora de cambiar los datos al **apretar el boton actualizar** me lanza el siguiente error : `Fallo al actualizar usuario` . He **debugeado** el codigo añadiendo `var_dump()` en las **consultas**, **en el paso del id..** pero pasa todos los datos perfectamente como lo muestro a continuacion:

```
C:\wamp64\www\CURSO_PHP_OO\crud\procesos\actualizar.php:33:
array (size=6)
  0 => string '14' (length=2)
  1 => string 'jose updated' (length=12)
  2 => string 'jose' (length=14)
  3 => string 'jose' (length=7)
  4 => string 'jose@gmail.com' (length=17)
  5 => string 'jose' (length=7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente encontree el **problema** , este reside en mi **funcion** `actualizar()`. Era por una **coma** que olvide a la hora de crear el `$sql` de mi `update`. Lo tenia de la siguiente manera :

```
    public function actualizar($datos){
        $c = new conexion();
        $conexion = $c->conectar();

        $sql = "
        UPDATE usuarios 
        SET 
        nombre = '$datos[1]', 
        apellidos = '$datos[2]', 
        usuario = '$datos[3]', 
        email = '$datos[4]' 
        password = '$datos[5]' 

        WHERE id = '$datos[0]'";

        return $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
    }
```

Como se puede observar entre el campo `email` y `password` olvide una coma [`,`].

Una vez corregido ya me lo actualiza **perfectamente**:

```
public function actualizar($datos){
            $c = new conexion();
            $conexion = $c->conectar();

            $sql = "UPDATE usuarios SET nombre = '$datos[1]', apellidos = '$datos[2]', usuario = '$datos[3]', email = '$datos[4]',password = '$datos[5]' WHERE id = '$datos[0]'";

            return $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
        }
```

Comment: Pero tu consulta como la tienes es vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*. Lee sobre ese tema cuando puedas. Y tu clase se puede organizar mejor, no tienes por qué conectar en cada método, la conexión puede ser un miembro de la clase y luego la usas desde los métodos con `$this`...  aunque una clase sólo con métodos es algo raro, pero bueno... También te sugiero que apliques las normas de la *convención de nombres*, por ejemplo, los nombres de clases deben ir siempre en `PascalCase`.

Comment: @A.Cedano El hecho de poner una  `$variable` de `php` en el **frontend** con una sentencia `sql` puede dar lugar a **inyeccion sql** , no?. Un saludo

Comment: Sí, porque esa variable puede ser cualquier cosa. Por ejemplo el dato con que se crea la variable puede ser manipulado, creando un código peligroso (y no solo a nivel de SQL sino de todo el sistema) y ese código se ejecutaría.